# Behaviour of length function on buffer sized not divisible by size of its type

Tags: glsl, language-lawyer

What will return the `length` function if buffer bound to 0 SSBO binding point is of size=36 (not divisible by size of uvec4 = 16)? And what's the rule?..

```
#version 430 core
layout(local_size_x=256) in;

layout(std430, binding=0) buffer B { uvec4 data[]; };

void main() {
    uint s = data.length();
    //some other code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a shader storage block, the `length()` method, on the unsized (run-time sized) array as its last member, will return an value of type `int`, calculated by the following formula:

```
max((buffer_object_size - offset_of_array) / stride_of_array, 0)
```

This means if a buffer with a size of 36 bytes is bound to the following shader storage block

```
layout(std430, binding=0) buffer B { uvec4 data[]; };
```

then `data.length()` will return *2*.

```
buffer_object_size = 36
offset_of_array    =  0
stride_of_array    = 16

max((36 - 0) / 16, 0) = 2
```

---

See [`ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object`; Issue (19)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt) (far at the end of the document):

> In this expression, we allow unsized arrays at the end of shader storage blocks, and allow the ".length()" method to be used to determine the size of such arrays based on the size of the provided buffer object. 
>   The derived array size can be derived by reversing the process described in issue (16):
>
> ```
> array.length() =
>     max((buffer_object_size - offset_of_array) / stride_of_array, 0)
> ```